# fields automatically added by django

Tags: django, django-orm

By default, [Django automatically gives each model an `id` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).
Are there any additional fields django's ORM adds automatically? Perhaps in specific cases?

Comment: Django's ORM is supposed to do so by default. It also creates the necessary fields in your db if you use relations.

Answer (score 3):

There are only 2 other situations I can think of where fields are automatically created. One is when sub-classing another model. The sub-class will inherit the parent's fields, [see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). The other is a Many-to-Many relationship. For a M2M relationship not only will a field get created but an entire intermediate table. [Again, the relevant docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)

Also, you can avoid having Django create the `id` field if you specify `primary=True` for the field you want to use as the primary key. [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

There are some other model/DB naming conventions as well. For example, the actual database table names will be prefixed with the Django app name that contains them plus an underscore. For example, a model named `Author` in an app named `library` will get called `library_author`. I'm sure there are other examples as well, so this is not an exhaustive list.